# Getting full value from table cell

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am pulling the value via ajax then pass it to my table to display data
but my aim is to get the actual value from the current selected cell in the table.

to display the user needs, I split the return value to get specific item

Here is my current script from ready event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {     

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getData',
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {                
        },            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var row = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                row += '<tr><td style="display:none;"  >' + (item.nameInfo).split("+")[0] + '</td><td>' + (item.nameInfo).split("+")[1]
                    + '</td><td>' + (item.nameInfo).split("+")[2]
                    + '</td><td>' + (item.nameInfo).split("+")[2]
                    + '</td></tr>'                        
            });
            $('#table1 tbody').html(row); // override previous results
        },
        complete: function (data) {                
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }

    });
});
```

the nameInfo colums looks like this and I need to capture the full details when the user click the cell:

```
+---------------------+
|     nameInfo        |
+---------------------+
|    juan+25+male     |
|    nina+14+female   |
|    zeb+20+male      |
+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions or comments TIA.

Comment: So `nameInfo` is what you're retrieving via ajax and you need to split the string at the "+" characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code: [Reference](http://dotnetlearners.com/javascript/find-table-cell-value-on-cell-table-click-using-javascript)

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("table1");
if (tbl != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
    }
}
function getval(cel) {
    alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
```